# ModuleNotFoundError when importing a module from a subdirectory in Python

Tags: python

I am facing an issue when trying to import a module from a subdirectory in my Python project. Here are the relevant details:
I have a Python file named dataset.py in the constants directory, and it defines a constant IMAGES_PATH:

```py
# constants/dataset.py
from pathlib import Path
IMAGES_PATH = Path('./data/mammals')
```

and I have this visualize.py file where I am importing dataset.py:

```py
# preprocessing/visualize.py

# ../constants/dataset.py
import constants.dataset as dt
```

but it throws this error

```bash
kosei@jack MINGW64 /c/dev/python/ml/mammals (master)
$ c:/dev/python/ml/mammals/.venv/Scripts/python.exe c:/dev/python/ml/mammals/preprocessing/visualize.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\dev\python\ml\mammals\preprocessing\visualize.py", line 4, in <module>
    import constants.dataset as dt
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'constants'
(.venv)
```

here is the file tree

```
.
├── constants
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── dataset.py
├── data
│   ├── mammals
│   └── readme.md
├── downloads
│   └── mammals-image-classification-dataset-45-animals.zip
├── models
│   └── image_classification_V0.py
├── preprocessing
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── visualize.py
├── requirements.txt
├── utils
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __pycache__
│   └── download_dataset.py
├── main.py
└── (.venv)
```

I also tried to use sys.path.append and it did not work.

Comment: close and reopen the editor. that might reset the folder settings if you just created the files...  it works fine for me.